# POST request with the Request modul in node not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request

I'm trying to send a POST request to my API using the `request` module but i get nothing back and when i console log the request data i see the fields are undefined as shown in the image below. Dont know why.
[image]

I've tried to solve the issue but no success. I don't know what is wrong. But when i try to send data to the same API via POSTMAN it works fine as seen in the image below. So i dont know why its not working when i send data from the front end of my app
[image]

i need help in figurig this out.

Heres's my server side code

```js
let express = require('express'),
 bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
 request = require('request'),
 //connect = require('connect'),
 jobRoutes = require('./routes/jobs'), //ddd
 // db   = require('./models/app'), //ddd
 // helpers = require('./helpers/jobs'),
 
 
 // fetch = require("node-fetch"),
 path = require('path'),
 router  = express.Router(),
 app = express(),
 port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 


app.use('/api/jobs', jobRoutes);

app.post('/jobs', (req, res)=>{
  let formBody = {
         title: req.title,
   category: req.body.category,
   description: req.body.description,
   type: req.body.type,
   url: req.body.url,
   email: req.body.email,
   apply: req.body.apply,
   location: req.body.location,
   company: req.body.company,       
         createdAt: Date.now()
             };
  request.post(console.log(formBody),{url:'http://localhost:3000/api/jobs/', form: formBody
  
   }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('upload failed:', err);
    }else{
     console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
   }
   return res.redirect('/jobs')
  });
 })
  
 app.listen(port, process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, ()=> console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`))
```

And here's what the receiving end server code looks like

```js
let db = require ('../models/app');

exports.createJob = (req, res) => {
 console.log('The req body:',req.body)
 db.Job.create(req.body)
 .then((newJob) => {
  res.status(201).json(newJob)
 })
 .catch((err) => {
  res.send(err)
 })

}
```

You can checkout the current [repo](https://github.com/seyicole/job-board) for more clarity

Comment: What does your request look like when making the request in the first example above?

Comment: Exactly like the way i posted it in the code snippet - `req.post`

Comment: The receiving end server does not appear to have a bodyParser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when i try to send data to the same API via POSTMAN it works fine as seen in the image below.

The image shows that the Content-Type of the request from Postman will be `application/json` but the code using the `request` module is going to send one with a Content-Type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Presumably (your "receiving end server code" does not show the bodyParser), your server only supports JSON formatted requests.

Either configure the server to support `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or make the request send JSON.